# ANGULAR - CARGA DE NAVEGADOR

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Tengo una pregunta como capturo el evento en el momento en el que se actualiza la pestaña del navegador?, No se si me deje entender!

LO QUE PASA QUE TENGO UN PROYECTO EN ANGULAR PERO NECESITO ESCUCHAR EN EL MOMENTO QUE EL CLIENTE RECARGA LA PAGINA, E INTENTADO CON ESTOS EVENTOS window.addEventListener PERO NADA!

Comment: Puede servirte el evento `onload` https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: Puede servirte el no usar mayúsculas sostenidas. Gritar no cambia nada. Y por favor, añade el código relacionado con lo que nos cuentas que has intentado y por qué dices que no funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando refrescas la pestaña navegador, se re-inicia todo el ciclo de vida de la app (y de sus componentes), por lo tanto las variables perderán todos sus valores (que no están almacenados en alguna bdd o en el localStorage) y se reiniciaran, de todas maneras existen algunas maneras de tratar ciertos datos si se almacenan en algún lado, por ejemplo el localStorage, una de estas maneras es ejecutar funciones en el `ngOnInit` o `ngOnDestroy`, pero dependerá de tus necesidades.
Te dejo este articulo acerca del ciclo de vida de los componentes en angular [aqui](https://medium.com/angular-chile/angular-componentes-y-sus-ciclos-de-vida-aa639e13a688).

Comment: Gracias!, si si ocupo localstorage!

Answer (score 0):

si usas una versión de angular 2 o mayor, re recomiendo que uses los eventos que maneja el [router](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events) que provee de Angular.

Este seria el ejemplo de uso, lo importas en tu componente en el constructor, y validas que sea el evento NavigationEnd, con eso cada que se cargue una nueva ruta en tu navegador estaras recibiendo el evento.

```js
  import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';


  //Importas el router en tu Constructor
  constructor (private router: Router) {
    router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe((event) => {

      //Filtra los eventos, de cuando tu router termino de hacer una navegación
      const varUrl = 'url';
      console.log(varUrl);
    });
    this.load();
  }
```

Solo si lo quieres usar en un componente especifico, de preferencia asígnalo a un subscriber, para que al destruir el componente se quite la subscripción, y no este duplicando el evento.

```js
  public subscriber: Subscription;
  constructor (private router: Router) {
    this.subscriber = router.events.pipe()...
  }

  ngOnDestroy () {
    this.subscriber?.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Gracias compañero!